# Spring Cache in a reactive application

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive, spring-cache

I am using the Spring Cache default implementation(ConcurrentHashMap):

```
@Bean
CacheManager cacheManager() {
    ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager = new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("mycache");
    cacheManager.setAllowNullValues(false);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Reactor [addons](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/tree/master/reactor-extra/src/main/java/reactor/cache) is used to get an item. On cache miss item is written to the cache:

```
public Mono<T> get(ID key) {
    return CacheMono.lookup(k -> findValue(k).map(Signal::next), key)
                    .onCacheMissResume(Mono.defer(valueRetriever(key)))
                    .andWriteWith((k, signal) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                        if (!signal.isOnError()) {
                            writeValue(k, signal.get());
                        }
                    }));
}

private void writeValue(ID key, T value) {
    if (value != null) {
        cache.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Does `cache.put(key, value);` considered a blocking call? Should be published on a different Scheduler?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

If you have the opportunity, I would suggest you to use ReactiveRedisConnection with [Lettuce](https://lettuce.io) instead.

You could for example setup your beans as follows:

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory() {
    final RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfig 
    = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(SpringBootApp.redisHost, SpringBootApp.redisPort);
    redisConfig.setPassword(SpringBootApp.redisPassword);
    redisConfig.setDatabase(0);
    final LettuceConnectionFactory connFac = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfig);
    return connFac;
}

@Bean
public ReactiveRedisConnection reactiveRedisConnection(final ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    return redisConnectionFactory.getReactiveConnection();
}

@Bean
public ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Object> redisOperations(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    final JdkSerializationRedisSerializer serializer = new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer();
    final RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Object> builder = RedisSerializationContext
            .newSerializationContext(new StringRedisSerializer());
    final RedisSerializationContext<String, Object> context = builder.value(serializer).build();
    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(factory, context);
}
```

Then you can use `ReactiveRedisOperations` to store/retrieve your data from your cache non-blocking. You could do something like:

```
   Mono.just("my_cache_key::" + uniqueId)
                .flatMap(key ->  reactiveRedisOps.opsForValue().get(key)
                        .cast(MyObj.class)
                        .switchIfEmpty(
                          getMyObjNonBlocking()
                           .flatMap(myObj -> ops.opsForValue().set(key, myObj, 
                                            Duration.ofMinutes(ttl))
                                            .thenReturn(myObj))
                        ));
```

Comment: Redis is not suitable solution for my case. Do you have any other solution to suggest? Which Scheduler do you think should be used?

Comment: Well, for blocking I/O Operations, you should use boundedElastic() as reactor documentations suggest, to avoid blocking the event loop

Comment: How can i use @Cacheable with this ?

Comment: I am also trying with @Cacheable annotation. I am not able to cache the response in redis server. Can you help me on the same if you able to achieve it